# past perfect continuous in negative sentence

Tags: grammar

I was wondering if it was possible to write that:

My mother had not been writing for so long

I know that "My mother had not written for so long" would be better. But imagine that the mother  wrote a lot to her daughter(may be 1 or 2 letters per day during 4 years) and then she stopped . Could the daughter tell after not receiving any letters for one month
"My mother had not been writing for so long "

Comment: The word "so" is causing me problems. Take it out and it sounds better.

Answer (score 2):

Continuous forms are often scene-setters. They create a backdrop on which to hang specific events at precise points in time, and using them creates an expectation. So when I read "My mother had not been writing for long", I expect an event set against this backdrop. For example: *when the phone rang*.

In your example the mother has stopped writing. Stopping is sudden; it is not a backdrop. A continuous form is therefore not appropriate. The daughter might say "My mother has not written for a month" or, to imply continuity in the past, "She used to write every day but she stopped about a month ago."

Answer (score 1):

Yes the grammatical form is correct if the context is in the past, but  I'd probably say:

- I had not been hearing from my mother for long.

But if your sister is saying it now:

- I have not been hearing from my mother for long.

**To hear from:**

To get a letter, telephone call, or transmitted communication from.

Source: Collins Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may use your example. Imagine a situation like in the following example:

> “I failed receiving letters because **my mother had not been writing for long**”.

This is an example of using past perfect continuous before another action in the past, which shows cause and effect.